# Can't Query All Fields in AllSubscribers List

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data-views

I need to grab fields within the AllSubscribers list. I attempted a simple query, but I'm getting the error "Invalid column name..." for the columns that I've commented out in the screenshot below. Is there a reason that I can't query for these fields? I wasn't able to find the AllSubscriber list data view in SFMC's documentation, so I'm not sure what my next step is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to directly query the 'All Subscribers' list.

You have 3 main options when querying data.

1. Use the [_Subscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) data view
2. Use the [_ListSubscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5) data view
3. Do a tracking extract and import into a DE

Please note that the Subscribers and ListSubscribers list do not contain any of the attributes that you entered into your list. This is because that is not the purpose of these data views.  You would need to instead look for [_enterpriseattribute](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_enterpriseattribute.htm&type=5) data view for these values.

Now, in general I would recommend querying the _Subscribers ID and then doing a join based on SubscriberID to the _enterpriseattribute data view to get further attribute details stored in your lists.

Your other option is to do a full tracking export, which should contain all the details you need.  If you need it to be queriable, you would then import this csv file into the DE and then you can query it similar to how you normally do.